# How to handle hardware keyboard enter for a view?

Tags: android, android-view

I am programmagitcallly creating an EditView with this code:

```
    mSearchBar = new EditText(this);

    mSearchBar.setHint("Enter sim name.");

    mSearchBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                layoutWidth,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    mSearchBar.setOnEditorActionListener(mEditorAction);

    mSearchBar.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);

    mSearchBar.setInputType(
              InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
            );
```

Then I have the mEditorAction with...

```
private OnEditorActionListener mEditorAction = new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            gotoSim(v.getText().toString());
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)SLMapTest.this
                .getSystemService(SLMapTest.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            mSearch.collapseActionView();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

However this code ( Which I got from a bit of googling ) doesn't play nice with hardware keyboards, apparently. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

attach `onKeyListener()` to your view and then in listener

in key listener
`if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)`
`//do something`